# Classical mechanical problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I have two planes, one characterized by equation $$\phi_1=f(x)-z=0$$ and another $$\phi_2=\alpha y-z=0$$ where $\alpha$ is arbitrary. In their line of intersection(we assume it exist and is continous) is moving a body with mass $m$, that was dropped from height $h$ and moving because of gr. force $F_g=(0,0,-mg)$. I have to solve lagrange's equations of the first kind and find an equation of movement of the body. Here is what i've done:
$$m\ddot{\vec{r}}=\vec{F}-\lambda\nabla\phi$$
that gives
$$m\ddot{x}=-\lambda_1f'(x)$$ $$m\ddot{y}=-\lambda_2\alpha$$  $$m\ddot{z}=-mg+\lambda_1+\lambda_2$$
and from derivation of the planes, we get
$$\dot{\phi}_1=f'(x)\dot{x}-\dot{z}=0\implies f'(x)=\dot{z}/\dot{x}$$
$$\dot{\phi}_2=\alpha\dot{y}-\dot{z}=0$$
$$\ddot{\phi}_1=f''(x)\dot{x}^2+f'(x)\ddot{x}-\ddot{z}$$
$$\ddot{\phi}_2=\alpha\ddot{y}-\ddot{z}$$
that, with combination with first equation is:
$$m\ddot{x}=-\lambda_1\frac{\dot{z}}{\dot{x}}$$
$$m\ddot{x}\dot{x}=-\lambda_1\dot{z}$$
$$m\dot{((1/2)\dot{x}^2)}=-\lambda_1\dot{z}$$
Now, I've multiplied all other equations, summed them, and get
$$1/2(m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2\dot{)}=\dot{z}(\lambda_2(1-\alpha)-mg)$$
integrated it and happily used the energy conservation(that I extracted from the equations) and was very surprised, when I got $$\lambda_2(z-\alpha y)=mgh$$
but $(z-\alpha y)=0$ from $\phi_2$. I realized, I can't integrate it, if $\lambda_i$ is a function of spatial coordinates(that are function of time) and now I am stuck. Am I missing some trick I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have integrated the equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left[\frac{m}{2} (\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot z^2) \right] = \dot z\left[\lambda_2 (1-\alpha) + mg\right]
$$
however, on the right hand side you have $\lambda_2$, how do you know this is independent of time?

You have all the pieces you need, in particular, showing that your equations of motion lead to conservation of energy means that you have a first order differential equation that you can integrate.  Starting from conservation of energy we know how to write $\dot y$, $\dot z$, ,and $z$ in terms of functions of $x$, that is, in terms of $\dot x$, $f(x)$, and $f'(x)$.  We can then find $t$ as an integral over $x$.  To go further we would need initial conditions and a form for $f(x)$.

Comment: I quote myself: "integrated it and happily used the energy conservation(that I extracted from the equations) and was very surprised, when I got
λ2(z−αy)=mgh
but (z−αy)=0 from ϕ2. **bold**(I realized, I can't integrate it, if λi is a function of spatial coordinates(that are function of time)...)" ?

Comment: The equation as written in my answer cannot be directly integrated.  As stated in the answer, starting from conservation of energy and applying the constraint equations leads to a first order differential equation for x(t).  I have not done the algebra for you.

Comment: That's what I said in the question and I cited the very part where I stated it for you in my comment. And no, equation $\dot{x}^2=2g(h-z)-\dot{z}^2(1-\frac{1}{\alpha^2})$ cannot be solved for $t$.